# Is the Midpoint Rule the average of the lower and upper estimates of an integral?

Tags: calculus

Does the average of the lower estimate, $L_n$,  and upper estimate, $R_n$, of an integral give the same or very similar approximation of an integral when using the Midpoint Rule or is there no relevant connection?

Where  $f$ is increasing

$$L_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_{i-1}) \Delta x$$

And

$$R_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_{i}) \Delta x$$

Does

$$\sum_{i=1}^n f(\frac{x_{i-1} + x_{i}} {2}) \Delta x  =  \frac{L_n + R_n}{2}$$?

Comment: You say lower and upper but what you actually write is the left and right rules. These are only the lower and upper sums if $f$ is increasing.

Comment: I see. That's how my textbook introduced the idea of finding the upper and lower approximations for the area under a curve, and yes I notice now that the book uses increasing functions. Back to the question, is the average or the upper and lower approximations the Midpoint Rule or approximates it?

Comment: No, it depends on the second derivative. E.g. for convex functions, what can we say about the midpoint vs the average of the 2 end-points?

Comment: In the case of increasing functions, the average of the upper and lower sum is the trapezoidal rule, and the relationship between the trapezoidal rule and the midpoint rule depends very much on the concavity. As a little exercise to play with this, consider the two approximants of $\int_0^1 x^{1/2} dx = \frac{2}{3}$ and $\int_0^1 x^2 dx = \frac{1}{3}$ (both increasing functions but with different concavity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $$f\left(\frac{x_{i-1} + x_i}{2}\right) = \frac{f(x_{i-1}) + f(x_i)}{2}$$
unless $f$ is linear. So your last equation is not true:

$$M_n := \sum_{i=1}^n  f\left(\frac{x_{i-1} + x_i}{2}\right) \Delta x_i \neq \frac{L_n + R_n}{2}$$

In general, it's not even true that $M_n$ will be between $L_n$ and $R_n$. If the function is increasing, then you know that $L_n \leq M_n \leq R_n$.

Also, this is not the lower or upper integral. This the left end point and right end point Riemann sum. In general, one cannot say which of $L_n$, $R_n$, or $M_n$ gives a better approximation. However, if $f$ is integrable, then you know that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} L_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} M_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} R_n = \int_a^b f$$